# ActionScript Flash Predefined Global Variables

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

Can anyone send me a link, or list all of the global variables that are predefined by Flash ActionScript 3? For example, like the current time, or the current frame, etc.?

Thanks,
Thommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not too sure if there is any. Generally you would use the stage or main movieClip object.

```
trace("frame: " + myMovieClip.currentFrame);

var now:Date = new Date();
trace("time: " + now.getTime());
```

I usually use a singleton pattern if i need global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is the language reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/all-index-Symbols.html

If by global variables, you mean Top Level classes/functions etc, you can check out: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-detail.html